# Активное окно iframe

Tags: jquery, javascript, iframe

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, как можно на javascript / jQuery сделать так, чтобы iframe был активным, т.е. как будто на него уже кликнули.

Спасибо.

Comment: Может быть, вы имеет ввиду pop-up (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%F1%EF%EB%FB%E2%E0%FE%F9%E5%E5_%EE%EA%ED%EE )?

Comment: нет, я имею ввиду именно iframe